# Would AWS cache Node.js modules once they are loaded?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I was looking for code examples of applications developed using the Serverless framework and Nodejs. I came across of the following example.

https://github.com/hammerspacecouk/tubealert.co.uk/blob/master/handler.js

From an unique handler, they load a module called DI.js.

https://github.com/hammerspacecouk/tubealert.co.uk/blob/master/src/DI.js

This module actually will load all the module dependencies for the application.

So how this works?.

Anytime there is a call to "POST: /subscribe", it will call to the handler "subscribe: (evt, ctx, cb)=>{}" which will load all the modules defined in DI.js?

Therefore, it is better to load all the modules in "one-go" or load the modules for each handler as it is needed?

Comment: To answer the question from the title, Node caches modules once they are loaded,  they are like Singletons where you can actually just access an instance in that regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you want to load all modules when starting a server, and not once for every request from a client.

But this is a **serverless** setup, designed to be run on AWS Lambda or similar. That means the handler is loaded into memory for the single request, and once it is finished the node instance exits. There is nowhere for the loaded modules to be cached.

This is the trade-off of using a serverless service. You have slightly longer response times as the server needs to load your code and its dependencies into memory from file, then execute it **for every request**.

The upside is that you do not have to pay for a server to be running 24/7 when you have less requests, and you don't have to worry about maintenance or scaling either once you get increased traffic.